# Is there a faster way to enumerate a collection of OData client objects?

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I have a customer list I load on the client application which has about 35k entries. It takes about 12 seconds to get the data from the server, then about 2.5 minutes to enumerate those results into something (IList) i can use. It seems like the performance issue I am having is with the OData proxy handling the object creation. I tried manually running through the IEnumerable and this is slightly faster that .ToList but nothing significant. I originally thought about streaming the results but the 12 seconds is not my problem.

Thanks for any thoughts/advice.

Comment: How much data is it, in bytes? Sounds sort of like your machine is swapping on harddrive. With the relatively low amount of information for us to work with you are likely to get mostly guesses.

Comment: I think you are correct, the amount of data returned over HTTP is about 16mb. What other information would be helpful? I am only fetching the customer records themselves, not expanding the related records. Doing that when a specific customer is selected and that performs fairly well. I am looking at this in the context of my data service. Right now, it returns a list of customers. That process boils down to a fetch of the data from the server, about 10-16 seconds, then the process of converting to a list that can be displayed, about 300 seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without using `AutoMapper`.

The `ProductsController` now looks like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductDTO> Get(ODataQueryOptions<ProductDTO> q)
    {
        IQueryable<Product> products = this._products.AsQueryable();

        IEdmModel model = GetModel();
        IEdmType type = model.FindDeclaredType("TestAPI.Models.Product");
        IEdmNavigationSource source = model.FindDeclaredEntitySet("Products");
        ODataQueryOptionParser parser = new ODataQueryOptionParser(model, type, source, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "$filter", q.Filter.RawValue } });
        ODataQueryContext context = new ODataQueryContext(model, typeof(Product), q.Context.Path);
        FilterQueryOption filter = new FilterQueryOption(q.Filter.RawValue, context, parser);

        if (filter != null) products = filter.ApplyTo(products, new ODataQuerySettings()) as IQueryable<Product>;
        return products.Select(p => new ProductDTO(p));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies. Perhaps you answered the wrong question?